# Use Tampermonkey to delinkify tel: links

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I'd like to use Tampermonkey to strip the `<a href="tel:` from telephone numbers on a webpage on our intranet.

I've installed Tampermonkey and bodged the following script

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Localhost Tel: link remover
// @author      Dan
// @match       *://localhost/*
// @version     2019.08.15
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js


console.log('Started Localhost Tel: killer...');

// ==/UserScript==
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('tel');

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  anchors[i].href = anchors[i].href.split("?")[0];
}
```

but I'm way out of my depth! I've tried Googling for "delinkify" and "strip links" but even if I could find someone suitable, I'm specifically looking to strip tel: links not just all links.

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        tel: remover
// @match       *redacted*
// @version     2019.08.15
// @run-at      document-end
// ==/UserScript==

const linksTel = [...document.querySelectorAll("a")].filter((link)=>link.href.startsWith("tel:"));

for(let linkTel of linksTel) {
    const parent = linkTel.parentNode;
    // Trim will remove extra spaces at the beginning and end
    const newTextNode = new Text(linkTel.innerText.trim());
    parent.replaceChild(newTextNode, linkTel);
}
   alert("check");
```

Comment: tel is not a tag name.  The tag in your example is `a`

Comment: Are you sure you want to use jquery specifically? It is possible to this with jQuery, but it is not necessary. And your current code is not using it, so this is not a Jquery problem per se.

Comment: Also, you need to use `@run-at document-end`, see my answer for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The tag name you're looking for is `a` as in `<a ... >`. So use:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
```

But that gives you **ALL** the links. So you will need to only filter for those that have `tel:` in the beginning. There's an utility method `.filter`, but it is only available for arrays, not `HTMLElementCollection` that is returned by document queries. You can unroll the collection in array like this:

```
const linksArray = [...links];
```

Now the filter:

```
const linksTel = linksArray.filter((link)=>link.href.startsWith("tel:"));
```

Now you have all the links that start with `tel`. To replace with just plain text node, you could do:

```
for(let linkTel of linksTel) {
    const parent = linkTel.parentNode;
    // Trim will remove extra spaces at the beginning and end
    const newTextNode = new Text(linkTel.innerText.trim());
    parent.replaceChild(newTextNode, linkTel);
}
```

That should be it.

Also mind this!  You use **@run-at document-start**. That's not what you want. You need to use `@run-at document-end`. At `document-start`, the HTML was not loaded yet, so you cannot manipulate it.

See it all together below:

```js
const linksTel = [...document.querySelectorAll("a")].filter((link)=>link.href.startsWith("tel:"));

for(let linkTel of linksTel) {
    const parent = linkTel.parentNode;
    // Trim will remove extra spaces at the beginning and end
    const newTextNode = new Text(linkTel.innerText.trim());
    parent.replaceChild(newTextNode, linkTel);
}
```

```html
<a href="tel:123456489">123456489</a><br />
<a href="/test">Tet page</a>
```

Comment: thanks for this Tomáš! Looks great, however, it's not yet working for me! I've edited my initial question to include the code as I'm running it, and if you notice the alert: "check" - unfortunately that displays WELL before the page is finished loading, despite the fact I'm instructing the code to only execute at `@run-at      document-end` - I have no doubt the code would work well if it would only wait for the page to finish loading.

Comment: `document-end` happens after the HTML is parsed, but it may still be rendering. Alert is not a good choice here. Try to instead do `console.log("Links:",linksTel)` and see if the array is empty. If it is, maybe the links are created dynamically by some script. To check that, press `Ctrl+U` in website to see the HTML source that was sent from server. If scripts are creating the links, there are solutions but they are either complicated or ugly.

Comment: Hi again Tomáš. Yes I think a CDN is involved and the HTML source is very minimal. I think it is script generated. Thank you.

Comment: @daneee Well, if you don't mind a dirty solution, just wrap the entire script in `setInterval`. If you want it clean, read about [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), which allows you to process any changes in HTML.